# How to set Toolbar in a Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, toolbar, appcompatactivity

I'm making a project with some fragment, each fragment has its own toolbar. But when I use AppCompatActivity in my fragment to setSupportActionBar, I'm facing below force close problem :

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.example.admin.prototypedemo, PID: 6090
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.prototypedemo/com.example.admin.prototypedemo.activity.TopScreenActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.example.admin.prototypedemo.activity.TopScreenActivity cannot be
>   cast to android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.example.admin.prototypedemo.activity.TopScreenActivity cannot be
>   cast to android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
>   at
>   com.example.admin.prototypedemo.fragment.TopScreenFragment.onCreateView(TopScreenFragment.java:50)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962) 
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:330)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1177)
>   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5461)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471) 
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175) 
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)  
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

Below are my codes:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup parent, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_screen_fragment_activity, parent, false);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Prototype");
        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity)getActivity();
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        return view;
}
```

Can anybody help me to fix this problem?
Many thanks!

Comment: Does your TopScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity?

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear your Activity does not extend AppCompatActivity. Make your activities extend AppCompatActivity from the support library instead of Activity.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar is added in actionbar whereas ActionBar is an Activity property. If you want to set a toolbar from a given fragment as the ActionBar of the owning Activity, then get the Activity that owns the fragment (Fragment.getActivity()) and set its ActionBar property.

You will obviously have to manage this carefully if your app has multiple fragments within that Activity.

Whereas 2nd solution is by implementing an interface in the activity and calling from the fragment class.